# What's the best way to determine how to balance a fighting game?

Tags: manual-testing

What'sa good way to balance a fighting game? Should I focus on HP, MP, items, spells, damage, or etc? If HP Values are in the thousands to 100 thousand, what should the damage numbers look like? I've never really created a complicated game with so many factors and stats to consider, so I'm interested in learning what is the best way to determine game balance before sending it off to a tester.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about QA or testing.

Comment: Maybe this is better for http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ or an game development forum, since the question is to open.

Comment: Those descriptions said "professional", and I'm not a pro, but move it if neccessary

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure it's the best place for this (don't see many game QA questions here), but balance is all about the relationship between things.

A simple way I've seen to manage stats is to just assign each stat a cost per unit. Then each fighter has the same budget. So then adjusting cost per unit on a given stat is a sort of lever or dial for you to balance with. You can even have that cost scale non-linearly.

It get's really complex when you try to model the utility of complex affordances like say a  fireball vs. a dragon punch. Those sorts of things are what you should look for from your testers. They can give you qualitative feedback on the things most difficult to quantify (fighter x is overpowered because of reason y).

Regarding the numbers, try doubling it if they feel too small or halving it if they feel too large. Keep going until you are satisfied with them.

Finally, when working with your testers you really get the most out of them when you can manage criticisms. Because without any idea of what your game is supposed to be, they are mostly left with telling you what they don't like about it (and hopefully why).